# how to Permanentaly remove data from stack once it has been pop out

Tags: java, stack

i want to remove the data permanently from the top of the stack once it has been pop out like

return Stack[top--]!

but when i again call pop out i get same as the last poped value!! so how to remove data once it has been poped out any hint!

thanks in advance please
(Need hints using java code)

Comment: You read the source for the Stack class in Java and it didn't give you any ideas?  From your description, I suspect the code isn't doing what you think as `top--` should prevent you from see the same value even though it will still be in the array. http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Stack.java.html

Comment: Sounds your using your own implementation of `Stack`, is that correct?

Comment: show us your code. The method `pop()` in `java.util.Stack` does this: Removes the object at the top of this stack and returns that object as the value of this function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Stack stack = new Stack();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) 
        stack.push(new Integer(i));


    while (!stack.empty())
        System.out.print(stack.pop() + " ");


    System.out.println(" No element in stack");
}
```

This works fine for me.